# When the Fed is in a hiking cycle or tightening cycle, the forwards are

Tags: fixed-income

Forwards are flatter in a hiking cycle because market is pricing in expectations of the Fed raising rates. Steeper trades would be carry positive correct?

Forwards are steeper in a hiking cycle because market is pricing in expectations of the Fed easing rates. Flattener trades would be carry negative correct?

Same thing for swaps?

Comment: Take a look at these answers https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/35795/carry-calculation-on-an-interest-rate-swap/35897#35897, or https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/36253/question-on-pure-carry-for-two-bonds/36261#36261. I would also strongly advise not falling into the trap of using the word 'carry' without necessarily knowing what it means or what scenario you are hypothesizing.

Comment: Yea you're right. There's pure carry (coupon less financing), total carry which includes pure carry and roll.